# MySQL events don't execute

Tags: mysql, events

I'm working in a QA server, which turns down every day at 22:00 and turns on at 06:00 and I have an event that must execute at 06:40 but it never does, except when the server stays on.

This is the EVENT conf:

```
CREATE EVENT test_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2021-12-15 06:40:00.000'
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO CALL schema.sp()
```

Comment: You better ask this question on the dedicated DBA sister site of SO as this is not a programming problem.

Comment: *ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE* Does your EP still exists? *but it never does* Check that ES is enabled on MySQL server start, check server's local time.

Comment: @SergioMoná *i test it and it is ON* When you have tested it? Schedule `SELECT @@event_scheduler;` execution via CLI (with `--tee=` option, or add `INTO OUTFILE`) in external scheduler (OS, cron, etc.) at 06:40 and look at the output after server restarting.

Answer (score -3):

enable the event scheduler or test if on

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler=ON;
```

see: https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/system-variables/event_scheduler/

it equal to MySQL

Comment: hi, i test it and it is ON

Comment: `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler=ON;` acts until MySQL restarts.

Comment: @Anika, Yes, but for testing its the fastet way